# Flatten the object gets the console logged thrice

Tags: javascript, object

When I use the code below to flatten the object, I get the console logged thrice. The object is to return or console ONE object i.e. `newObj`

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Data Input**

```
const data = {
    id: 09,
    email: 'abc@test.com',
    contactInfo: {
        name: 'Test1',
        address: {
            city: 'Berlin',
            country: 'Germany'
        }
    }
}
```

Over here I am Flattening the Object through recursive calls.

```
const newObj = {}

const getFlattenObj = (data) => {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        if (typeof data[key] === 'object') {
            getFlattenObj(data[key]);
        } else {
            newObj[key] = data[key]
        }
    })

    console.log(newObj);
}

getFlattenObj(data);
```

Comment: you get the console logged thrice because the `console.log(newObj);` runs three times.

Comment: If I console out of the object, it returns empty. How can I fix it?

Comment: `data` is three levels deep.

Comment: if you write `console.log(newObj);` after `getFlattenObj(data);`, you'll see your `newObj`;

Comment: What if I don't add a console log I want the object to populate on the function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are logging inside the `getFlattenObj` which is a recursive function, since it calls itself when the value of a key is an object.

So the initial call is one, then the code will encounter the `contactInfo` key and call `getFlattenObj` again, so another log, and then that second call will encounter the `address` key and call `getFlattenObj` once more. So three calls to `getFlattenObj` is 3 logs.

---

An additional improvement you could add, is to not use a global variable for the `newObj` but instead pass it or create it inside the method, so you can reuse the function multiple time without having to manually clear the object.

```js
const data = {
  id: 09,
  email: 'abc@test.com',
  contactInfo: {
    name: 'Test1',
    address: {
      city: 'Berlin',
      country: 'Germany'
    }
  }
}

const getFlattenObj = (data, targetObject = {}) => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof data[key] === 'object') {
      getFlattenObj(data[key], targetObject);
    } else {
      targetObject[key] = data[key]
    }
  })
  return targetObject;
}

const newObj = getFlattenObj(data);
console.log(newObj);
```